# Lat long coordinates mapped incorrectly in Processing 3, need rotation

Tags: xml, gps, maps, processing, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to make a very basic Processing 3 sketch, where I map out the latitude and longitude points that my watch tracks on my bike rides.

I'm able to parse the XML data from the location source, and I've set up a data folder with the XML file.  I don't seem to have a problem with parsing the data.

However, I am trying to Map the lat/long GPS data to the screen dimensions, and I don't think it's working out right.

I got it working in terms of lat/long showing up in the correct proportions.  **Although now, it's rotated incorrectly.**

I've attached an image.  The Left image is how it looks, and the Right image is how it should look.  It looks like the the dots/GPS need to be rotated 90deg counterclockwise.

[image]

Maybe it's something with my map()?

```
// convert and remap Lat and Long based on range
// -122.5367,37.6659,-122.3383,37.8174
float mainx = map(pointLat, 37.6659, 37.8174, 0, width); 
float mainy = map(pointLong, -122.5367, -122.3383, 0, height);
```

Anyways, here's my Processing code.  Any help is appreciated, as I've gotten stuck and I think this is the last bit to fix.

Thanks!
Aaron

```
// Example XML
//<Workout workoutActivityType="HKWorkoutActivityTypeCycling" duration="44.19382538398107" durationUnit="min" totalDistance="7.644061515836529" totalDistanceUnit="mi" totalEnergyBurned="300.3060000000002" totalEnergyBurnedUnit="kcal" sourceName="Aaron’s Apple Watch" sourceVersion="4.3" creationDate="2018-05-01 08:35:07 -0700" startDate="2018-05-01 07:50:51 -0700" endDate="2018-05-01 08:35:03 -0700">
//<MetadataEntry key="HKTimeZone" value="America/Los_Angeles"/>
//<MetadataEntry key="HKWeatherTemperature" value="49 degF"/>
//<MetadataEntry key="HKWeatherHumidity" value="82 %"/>
//<WorkoutRoute sourceName="Watch" sourceVersion="11.3" creationDate="2018-05-01 08:58:53 -0700" startDate="2018-05-01 07:51:11 -0700" endDate="2018-05-01 08:34:52 -0700">
// <MetadataEntry key="HKMetadataKeySyncVersion" value="2"/>
// <MetadataEntry key="HKMetadataKeySyncIdentifier" value="F2BEA6D4-4E7E-4867-AAF4-05586B2F753D"/>
// <Location date="2018-05-01 07:51:11 -0700" latitude="37.7514" longitude="-122.493" altitude="74.0396" horizontalAccuracy="2.43753" verticalAccuracy="1.71176" course="28.125" speed="1.56585"/>

gpsPoint[] gpsPoints;

PImage backgroundMap;

float mapScreenWidth,mapScreenHeight;  // Dimension of map in pixels.

XML xml;

void setup() {
  size(400, 386); // 7x7
  //background(255);
  backgroundMap   = loadImage("img/7x7.png");
  mapScreenWidth  = width;
  mapScreenHeight = height;
  image(backgroundMap,0,0,mapScreenWidth,mapScreenHeight);
  smooth();

  xml = loadXML("data/bikeRides.xml");
  XML[] workoutRoutes = xml.getChildren("Workout/WorkoutRoute");

  println("num of workouts " + workoutRoutes.length);

  // Parse inside Workouts, workout O
  for (int i = 0; i < workoutRoutes.length; i++) {
    //int workoutNumber = i+1;
    //println("Workout # " + workoutNumber + " //////" );

    //workout #1, list Locations, workout 0, Locations in there, go into an Array, get OVERWRITTEN every time?  empty Location array everyime
    XML[] locations = null;
    locations = workoutRoutes[i].getChildren("Location");
    println("number of locations in workout: " + locations.length);

    //initialize object with number in array, which is number of locations
    gpsPoints = new gpsPoint[locations.length];

    //add xvalue and yvalue into object
    for (int a = 0; a < locations.length; a++){

      //get lat and long
      float pointLat = locations[a].getFloat("latitude");
      float pointLong = locations[a].getFloat("longitude");

      // convert and remap Lat and Long based on range
      // -122.5367,37.6659,-122.3383,37.8174
      float mainx = map(pointLat, 37.6659, 37.8174, 0, width); 
      float mainy = map(pointLong, -122.5367, -122.3383, 0, height); 

      gpsPoints[a] = new gpsPoint(mainx, mainy);
      gpsPoints[a].display();

    }
  }
}

void draw() {  
}

class gpsPoint {

  float prevX;
  float prevY;
  float newX;
  float newY;

  gpsPoint(float previousX, float previousY){
    prevX = previousX;
    prevY = previousY;
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0, 50);
    point(prevX, prevY);
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing latitude and longitude. If you want the top of your sketch to be North then it is *latitude* that should be mapped to `y`, but you are mapping longitude to `y`.

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This question has also been posted [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/cant-seem-to-map-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-correctly-in-processing-3/734).

Comment: That solved it, thank you!